# Access elements inside JSON (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recordset, mssql-jdbc

I am retrieving data from ms sql database as a record set. I am trying to access the values in the record set, however am not able to access it because it is enclosed inside record set. 
Below is an example of the output I get from the database. The example result shows the output from the debugger.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfVEC.jpg

I want to access the elements such as start time, job number, etc inside the record  set.  How would I do this?

```
b.executeSql(sql, function (rows, err) {
    var jobdata = JSON.stringify(rows); //this is where i get the recordsets
    if (err) {
        // httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        console.log("Error with connection");
    }
    else {
        var Jdata = JSON.parse(jobdata); // I then use parse to try and acces elements

      console.log(Jdata.StartTime); //but this is undefined
```

}

What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Edit :
this is the output I got when I used - console.log(rows);

```
  { recordsets: 
  [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { StartTime: 2018-11-01T15:28:51.000Z, JobNumber: null } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ] }
```

Comment: Why would you stringify something and then immediately parse it again? That doesn't make much sense. Try `console.log(rows)` and post the data structure (as text, not as an image)

Comment: As @CertainPerformance mentioned, pl post the value you get from rows here. We might probably not need to stringify and parse again. Something as simple as accessing nested keys should get you your expected result.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added the output i receive when I used console.log(rows); without stringify

Comment: @DineshPandiyan I have added the output. Thanks

Comment: Looks like `StartTime` is not a property of the outer object, so accessing the `.StartTime` of the outer object doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rows object will always have `recordset` array with values, this is how you'll access it

```
const StartTime = rows.recordset[0].StartTime;
const JobNumber = rows.recordset[0].JobNumber;
```

```js
rows = {
  recordsets: [
    [
      // [Object]
    ]
  ],
  recordset: [{
    StartTime: '2018 - 11 - 01 T15: 28: 51.000 Z',
    JobNumber: null
  }],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [1]
};

const StartTime = rows.recordset[0].StartTime;
const JobNumber = rows.recordset[0].JobNumber;

console.log(`StartTime is - ${StartTime}`);
console.log(`JobNumber is - ${JobNumber}`);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, and it's work as champ ..! Thanks Again